# .htaces and .htpasswd give error?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Well, I'm trying to secure my xampp with .htaccess and .htpasswd and I don't see a mistake, so do many other developers that I know...

My .htaccess:

```
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/secret/hidden/place/.htpasswd
require valid-user
php_flag register_globals on
```

My .htpasswd:

```
wscript:$apr1$Y107OG1n$Ui6D997SqhERXXyV9VBU51
```

The error is error 500

Anyone?

Comment: Check your Apache error.log file and see what what error you're getting there.

Answer (score 1):

You should consult your error logfile usually located at: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Without knowing the exact error there's really only speculation as to what might be the issue.

```
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/apache/var/www/site/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

- *require valid-user* should be capital "**R**"
- **AuthUserFile** is usually located one directory above the web root.
- The permissions on the .htaccess and .htpasswd need to be set so that Apache can read them: **chmod 0644 .htaccess chmod 0644 .htpasswd**

( [further reading](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) )